# Doctrine 2 new proxies are not used after being regenerated

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, proxy

I have now run out of ideas and Google is not helping either. I believe the issue is rather simple to solve, but currently I am not seeing why it happens. Everything works fine on my testing environment with dev mode.

But doesn't work on production where the dev mode is off and proxy files need to be generated manually.

The first time I generated proxy files on the production environment, everything worked fine. Now I needed to improve some of the entities and when I use the "doctrine orm:generate-proxies" command again, then all the proxy files get generated and when I look at the new entity proxy files, then I can see that the new column are mapped.

But when I try to save or load new object, then nothing gets saved or load to the new columns. It is as if doctrine 2 doesn't understand, that there are new proxy files that it should use. Instead, it keeps on using some other hidden old proxy files, cached away in some dark end.

Any idea why doctrine 2 doesn't use the newly generated proxy files?

For extra clarity, this the the Doctrine Initialisation code.

```
$paths = array(__DIR__ . '/../ORM/Definition/Doctrine2/Entity');

        $isDevMode = false;
        $autoGenerateProxyClasses = AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_NEVER;

        if ($this->serverDevelopment()) {
            $isDevMode = true;
            $autoGenerateProxyClasses = AbstractProxyFactory::AUTOGENERATE_ALWAYS;
        }

        $dbParams = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => 'REMOVE',
            'password' => 'REMOVE',
            'dbname' => 'REMOVE',
            'host' => 'REMOVE'
        );

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
        $config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/../ORM/Definition/Doctrine2/Entity/Proxy');
        $config->setProxyNamespace('Database\ORM\Definition\Doctrine2\Entity\Proxy');
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($autoGenerateProxyClasses);

        $this->entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to generate proxies:

```
$em = Zend_Registry::get('em');
    $proxyFactory = $em->getProxyFactory();
    $metadatas = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
    $proxyFactory->generateProxyClasses($metadatas, APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Proxies');
```

**I have Proxies folder inside models folder.**

Try generating proxies using this code.

Comment: Have tried your code. It didn't help either. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. But I'm not sure, if it was the permissions or the user. But I changed the folder from 775 to 777 and also the user. Now it works :)